# xcode throwing "DetailViewController *" to prarameter of incompatible type warning when trying to implement camera functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

So I'm trying to implement a camera functionality for my ObjectiveC app. I have a `MasterViewController` that has a `tableview`. The `DetailViewController` handles viewing details of `cells` and adding new info. I have a camera button on my `navbar` that I want to open the system camera stuff and be able to grab images from there.

The only problem, my `UIImagePickerController` won't let me set my `DetailViewController` as delegate for some reason. It's just throwing the warning in the title of this post. I've made sure that delegate is properly implemented. A similar post recommended that `navigationcontrollerdelegate` be implemented as well, so I did that.

As it stands, I *think* that the camera won't work until I can set the delegate properly. I've attached the code from the class in question here:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "BucketItem.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_detailItem release];
    [_masterPopoverController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

-(void)setCellForEditing:(UITableViewCell*)cell
{
    cellBeingEdited = cell;
}

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [_detailItem release];
        _detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if(cellBeingEdited != nil)
    {
        NSUInteger cellNumber = [self.data.bucketItemCells indexOfObject:cellBeingEdited];
        BucketItem *item = [self.data.bucketItems objectAtIndex:cellNumber];
        titleInputBox.text = item.title;
        descriptionInput.text = item.description;
        isCompletedSwitch.on = item.isCompleted;
        date = item.date;
        imageView.image = item.image;
    }
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
    UIBarButtonItem * doneButton =[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(saveObject:)] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem * cameraButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(takePicture:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: doneButton, cameraButton, nil];

}

-(void) takePicture:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    }
    else
    {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }
    DetailViewController *tmp = self;
    [imagePicker setDelegate: tmp];

}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(void) saveObject:(id)sender
{

    UIImage *image = nil;
    if(imageView.image != nil)
    {
        image = imageView.image;
    }
    if(cellBeingEdited == nil)
    {
        [self.data addNewItemWithTitle: titleInputBox.text
                        andDescription: descriptionInput.text
                       thatIsCompleted: isCompletedSwitch.on
                              withDate: date
                             withImage: image];

    }
    else
    {
        NSUInteger cellNumber = [self.data.bucketItemCells indexOfObject:cellBeingEdited];
        BucketItem *item = [self.data.bucketItems objectAtIndex:cellNumber];
        item.title = titleInputBox.text;
        item.description = descriptionInput.text;
        item.isCompleted = isCompletedSwitch.on;
        item.date = date;
        item.image = image;
        [self.data.bucketItemCells replaceObjectAtIndex:cellNumber withObject:[self.data cellWithBucketItem:item]];
    }
    MasterViewController *vc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [vc.tv reloadData];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

-(IBAction) onSwitchToggle:(id)sender
{
    if(isCompletedSwitch.on == YES)
    {
        date = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1.0] retain];
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [format setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        dateLabel.text =[format stringFromDate: date];
        [format release];
    }
    else
    {
        date = nil;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Detail", @"Detail");
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField* )aTextField
{
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - Split view

- (void) navigationController: (UINavigationController *) navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
}

-(void) navigationController: (UINavigationController *) navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
}

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{

}



- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}
@end
```

Here's the .h file as requested:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *titleInputBox;
    IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionInput;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *isCompletedSwitch;
    IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    NSDate *date;
    UITableViewCell *cellBeingEdited;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (readwrite, assign) BucketListDataSource *data;

-(IBAction) onSwitchToggle:(id)sender;

-(void)setCellForEditing:(UITableViewCell*)cell;

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
@end
```

Comment: Show your .h file for DetailViewController

Comment: Please don't post so much code. Show the code giving the error. And show the class interface declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you didn't declare that your class conforms to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol. Update your .m by changing this line:

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
```

to:

```
@interface DetailViewController () <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Some people might add this to the `@interface` line in the .h file but unless other classes need to know that your view controller conforms to the delegate protocol, it is better to add it to the class extension in the .m file.

Also, the following code:

```
DetailViewController *tmp = self;
[imagePicker setDelegate: tmp];
```

should just be:

```
imagePicker.delegate = self;
```

**Update**: Now that you have posted your .h, please note that you should not declare the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods in your .h file as part of the class's interface. Adding the protocol does this for you. Remove these from your .h file:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

Comment: You definitely don’t want to add the delegate declaration in the private interface, you’d want to add it to the public interface in the .h file.

Comment: @eyebrowsoffire Why? I put as many in the .m as possible. It works just fine. There is no reason to tell the world that a class's implementation requires that it conform to some protocol.

Comment: Except that the control that calls the delegate methods is not confined to this file...

Comment: @eyebrowsoffire That doesn't matter. In this case, all that matters is that the compiler knows that the delegate actually conforms to the proper protocol. My answer fulfills that need. Try it. It works just fine.

Comment: The protocal declaration is in the .h file...

@interface DetailViewController: UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

Comment: @ScubaSteve Can you please see the comments added below your question and update your code as requested. Thanks.

Comment: @ScubaSteve You need to add that to your question so people can see it. Also, all of those protocols should be moved from the .h to the class extension in the .m. And lastly, see my updated answer.

Comment: first of all, xcode (most recent) doesn't even let me declare the protocals in the implementation file, second, if they're declared properly in the .h, then the declarations are not the problem so why would i move it to the .m file?

Comment: @ScubaSteve Of course Xcode will let you put them in the .m file. Do it just like I showed in my answer. But you are right - in the .h or the .m has no real bearing on your problem. Did you change the other lines (setting the delegate) I showed in my answer?

Comment: ah.. yeah i set the delegate like that as part of the troubleshooting process.. i also tried [imageView setDelegate:self] and none of them have worked

Comment: heh, whaddayaknow.. putting the declaration in the .m killed the warning

Comment: removed those declarations from the .h too.. i added them while troubleshooting

Comment: @ScubaSteve You never present the image picker in your `takePicture` method.

Comment: You need to call `[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: ah yeah i just figured that out from the tutorial i was following